# Como fazer o gráfico começar no eixo y pelo ggplot?

Tags: r, ggplot2, rgraph

Olá,

Estou tentando fazer com que o gráfico abaixo comece no eixo y, mas não estou conseguindo. A ideia é trazer o primeiro valor do eixo x, o tempo 6h, para o valor 0 do eixo y. Abaixo segue o script usado e a imagem obtida.

Alguém poderia me ajudar??

Muito obrigado!!

```
ggplot(Transporters_All_DEGs, 
     aes(x=TimePoint,y=log2FC,group=GeneID,colour=Species.x))+
     theme_bw()+
     theme(legend.position="bottom")+
     xlab("")+
     ggtitle("Relative expression")+
     geom_line(alpha = 1/20)+
     scale_color_manual(values=c("#920000", "#6DB6FF"))+
     geom_line(data=x2, aes(x=TimePoint,y=Log2meanFC, group=Species.x,colour=Species.x),size=2)+ 
     scale_colour_manual(name="",breaks=c("organism1","organism2"),labels=c("organism1","organism2"),values=c("#920000", "#6DB6FF"))+
     scale_x_discrete(limits=c("6h","12h","24h"))+
     annotate("text", label = paste(length(unique(Transporters_All_DEGs[which(Transporters_All_DEGs$Species.x == 'organism1'),'GeneID'])),'genes',sep=' '), x = '24h', y = 12, size = 4, colour = "#6DB6FF")+
     annotate("text", label = paste(length(unique(Transporters_All_DEGs[ which(Transporters_All_DEGs$Species.x == 'organism2'),'GeneID'])),'genes',sep=' '), x = '24h', y = 11, size = 4, colour = "#920000")
```

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Answer (score 1):

Para começar do 0, basta adicionar o comando `ylim(0,NA)`. Por exemplo:

```
ggplot(mtcars, aes(x = disp, y = mpg)) + geom_point()
```

Retorna este gráfico:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Já, com este termo adicionado:

```
ggplot(mtcars, aes(x = disp, y = mpg)) + geom_point() + ylim(0,NA)
```

Retorna:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: Será que era isto mesmo que o OP queria? A frase "A ideia é trazer o primeiro valor do eixo **x**, o tempo 6h, para o valor 0 do eixo **y**" (grifos meus) me sugere uma translação nos dados. Posso estar errado, mas entendi que ele não quer o gráfico dos pontos (x, y), mas sim (x-6, y) ou (x, y-min(log2FC)). Não tenho certeza do que ele realmente quer porque a frase que citei acima soa ambígua para mim. Não sei o que significa exatamente "trazer o primeiro valor do eixo **x**, o tempo 6h, para o valor 0 do eixo **y**".

Comment: Realmente está ambíguo. Na primeira vez que li não tive dúvidas de que era isso. Agora já não sei mais... acho que ele quer o contrário. Que o eixo x comece no 6h

Comment: Mas o eixo x já começa em 6h. Enfim, está esquisito. Eu não tenho certeza de que a minha interpretação está correta, e nem que a tua está errada.